# Assign unique ID to equivalent rows in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations, permutation

I would like to compute an `id` variable based on the unique combination of two (or more) variables. Consider the simple example below:

```
# Example dataframe
mydf <- data.frame(var1 = LETTERS[c(1, 2, 1)], var2 = LETTERS[c(2, 1, 3)])
mydf

# var1 var2
# A    B
# B    A
# A    C
```

Here, rows 1 and 2 should have the same `id` because `AB` and `BA` represent a combination of the same elements. Row 3 however, has a different `id` since the `AC` combination appear only once.

```
# Desired output
cbind(mydf, cid = c(1, 1, 2))

# var1 var2 cid
# A    B    1
# B    A    1
# A    C    2
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could benefit from `factor` type in base R for that:

```
mydf$cid <- as.numeric(factor(apply(mydf,1,function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ""))))
```

It disregards the order by which the equivalent rows are appeared in data frame. `cumsum` does not work once, for example, the rows 2 and 3 are switched in your data frame.

Answer (score 2):

We can `sort` by row, create a logical `vector` with `duplicated` and get the `cumsum`

```
cbind(mydf, cid = cumsum(!duplicated(t(apply(mydf, 1, sort)))))
```

Comment: Fails if, for example, the rows 2 and 3 are swapped in `mydf`.